# Is there a word, or description of someone who uses words like always, everytime, never

Tags: word-request

Not sure if I'm asking the question correctly but I thought I had come across the word that defines that can of talk. For example:

> I'm always sick
>   Teacher picks on me every day
>   You never text me

(Absolutes that just aren't true.)

Comment: Sith, if you've seen Star Wars ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could call this kind of speech **hyperbole**:

> **[hyperbole](http://wordnik.com/words/hyperbole)** (*n.*)  A figure of speech in which exaggeration is used for emphasis or effect, as in *I could sleep for a year* or *This book weighs a ton*.

And, if you really wanted a word to describe such people, you could call them *hyperbolists*:

> **[hyperbolist](http://wordnik.com/words/hyperbolist)** (*n.*) One who uses hyperbole; an exaggerator.

although it should be noted that *hyperbolist* is a rather rare word, and might seem a little awkward in casual conversation. (As a matter of fact, my spellchecker is putting a red line under it now.)

So, I don't think I'd ever say:

> *Bob is such a hyperbolist!*

Instead, I'd probably say:

> *Bob exaggerates all the time*.

(but then I'd be guilty of hyperbole, too).

Comment: More colloquially, Bob (not just Alice) might often be called a [***drama queen***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drama-queen) if he/she habitually describes / reacts to every situation in an overdramatic or exaggerated manner.

Comment: I agree with this. But, I point out too that it is ***possible*** that a person who says "I'm always sick" may also get sick very often. [upvoting]. I always get into trouble with my answers. [?]